# Possibly bricked moto g4 plus XT1644

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g-4g

I was trying to flash the official OTA for Android Nougat in XT1644 since the OTA hadn't get.

After reading, found [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/how-to/xt1644-stock-marshmallow-to-nougat-t3540022), and now my Moto G doesn't start properly, it says something like "failed to verify boot image". I ran this tutorial while working on Ubuntu 16.04 having installed adb-tools and fastbool-tools package.

Decided finally unlock bootloader (which worked) and install TWRP (which did not work), and here's the output for the TWRP flash:

[image: fail]

How can I manage to install the official Nougat update for XT1644?

Comment: Did you try what is discussed here? : https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/how-to/ota-zip-update-npj25-93-14-t3539407

Comment: @esQmo I can't boot into recovery mode, since TWRP failed, so I can't flash this version.

Comment: This version can only be flashed through a stock recovery, not TWRP! If you are unable to boot into recovery, then you'll need to flash your phone with RSD Lite.

Comment: Or simply using fastboot commands. The steps are here: https://www.gammerson.com/2016/05/guide-flash-stock-firmware-moto-g4-plus-2016-variants.html

Comment: Thanks. All those system images are not present in the unzipped file you told me to download. How should I proceed?

Comment: Download the firmware here, 1.0 GiB file: https://firmware.center/firmware/Motorola/Moto%20G4%20%28Plus%29/Stock/XT1644/

Comment: If I'm doing manual, just unzip the firmware and execute the commands you told me?

Comment: Yes, simply like that

Comment: But from the terminal, you have to `cd`  to where the files are unzipped then execute the command. .

Comment: @esQmo is this firmware for Nougat?

Comment: I don't​ think so, but it's for unbricking the device. You can try reflashing any Nougat update later.

Comment: So in Linux isn't working, I'm going to have to try in Windows

Comment: Should work if you unzip the flash file into the folder where fastboot is stored

Comment: when flashing partition, boot and systems, returns FAILED.